# How to show a message if a file is not uploaded in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

I'd like to show a modalDialog if users forget to uploade a label file. However, my modalDialog never shows up. Any suggestions? Thanks!

server.R:

```
function(input, output, session) {

    # Read in labels

    labels <- eventReactive (input$inFile2, {
      ldata = read.csv(input$inFile2$datapath, header=input$header2)
      return(ldata[, 1])
    })

    # Go to next tab only if labels are uploaded

    observeEvent(input$act_next, {
      if(nlevels(labels())> 0) {
        updateTabsetPanel(session, "allResults", 'selVars')
      } else {
        #if(is.null(input$inFile2$size)) {
          showModal(modalDialog(strong(h5("Please upload labels.")), easyClose = TRUE, footer = NULL))            
        #}
      }
    })
}
```

ui.R:

```
fluidPage(title = "Segmentation App", theme = shinytheme("spacelab"),

navbarPage("Segmentation", id = "allResults",
    tabPanel(value ='inputData', title = 'Data Import',
        verticalLayout(
              h4("Import labels for the independent variables"),
              fileInput(inputId="inFile2", "Choose a CSV File",
                          accept = c(
                          "text/csv",
                          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                          ".csv"
                        )
              ),

              checkboxInput("header2", "Header", TRUE),
              br(),
              actionButton("act_next", strong("Next!"))
        )
    ),

    tabPanel(value ='selVars', title = 'Data Preparation',
             verticalLayout(
             )
    )
```

)
)

Example of a CSV file to load:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eventReactive` does a `req` check on its event expression by default. If the file hasn't been uploaded yet and `input$inFile2` is null, no further reactive expressions will be evaluated after `labels()` has been called. So the modal code won't even run.

You could change `labels` from an `eventReactive` to a `reactive`, or specify `ignoreNULL = FALSE` in the `eventReactive` args. And make sure to return null when `input$inFile2` is null.